# Замена текста jQuery методом replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Кто подскажет, почему это не работает?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $('td').text().replace('1', 'Да');
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Приведите рабочий пример, в котором это не работает. Причин может быть довольно много.

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<script>
    window.onload=function(){
            $('td').text().replace('1','Да');
        }                       
</script>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
</table>`

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте этот код в вопрос. Под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1043269/edit). В комментарии его читать очень сложно.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko сделал сниппет, пробуйте )

Comment: @NickVolynkin тонкий юмор засчитан :-) Начал делать ответ, потому что подумал что ТС прислушался, поправил вопрос и даже сделал сниппет. А это, оказывается, были вы :-)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ну мне самому было интересно попробовать.

Comment: Простите, я хотел, но не успел

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас здесь две проблемы:

1. `$('td')` - возвращает коллекцию элементов, т.е. их несколько и соотвественно, надо каждый элемент обрабатывать отдельно в данном случае.
2. Результат выполнения `replace` никуда не присваивается, он просто пропадает.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $('td').each((i, el) => { // проходим по каждому элементу массива
    const $el = $(el);
    const replacedText = $el.text().replace('1', 'Да'); // заменяем значения
    $el.text(replacedText); // устанавливаем новое значение
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Забавно, но я всё ещё вижу `1 0 0`, потому что «Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js ("script-src").»

Comment: А у меня всё получилось. Спасибо автору комментария большое, +

Comment: @NickVolynkin интересно, что это за браузер такой строгий у вас?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko обычный FF.